# JAVA, poner el día correcto en función del mes que se añade

Tags: java

**JAVA, poner el día correcto en función del mes que se añade**
En el caso del mes y día, una vez entrado el mes, se pedirá el día. El texto que se mostrará por pantalla debe ser:
día:

es que, en función del mes, de indique en este texto los valores límites de día. Por ejemplo, en caso de julio:
día (1-31):

en caso de junio:
día (1-30):

y en caso de febrero:
día (1- 29):

Y en los otros meses lo deje en max 31, ahora mismo tengo el codigo que todos los dias tienen de min 1 y de max 31

lo tengo definido así:

````
                ```System.out.print("mes: ");
                        valorCorrecto = lector.hasNextInt();
                        if (valorCorrecto) {
                            mes = lector.nextInt();
                            if ((mes < MIN_MES || mes > MAX_MES)) {
                                dadaCorrecta = false;
                                System.out.println("te has equivocado de valor");
                            } else { ```
````

EL MIN_MES es 1 y MAX_MES es 12

entiendo que la mejor opción seria crear un switch pero no se como ya, alguna ayuda por favor, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo del todo tu pregunta. 
Que se le solicita al usuario por pantalla un número entre 1 - 12 que se corresponde con los meses Enero - Diciembre.
Una vez que tienes el mes quieres que el usuario introduzca un número de día que sea válido dependiendo del mes seleccionado no?

Yo haría esto

```
boolean flagDia = false;

while(!flagDia){
    if(enteroMes==2)
    {
        System.out.println("Debes introducir un numero entre 1-29");
        //Aqui usas el codigo que tengas para obtener es numero de dia y lo almacenas en una variable numeroDia
        if(MIN_DIA<=numeroDia<=29{
            flagDia = true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("El numero introducido no es valido, debe estar comprendido entre 1-29");
        }
    }
    else if(enteroMes==6)
    {
        System.out.println("Debes introducir un numero entre 1-30");
        //Aqui usas el codigo que tengas para obtener es numero de dia y lo almacenas en una variable numeroDia
        if(MIN_DIA<=numeroDia<=30{
            flagDia = true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("El numero introducido no es valido, debe estar comprendido entre 1-30");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Debes introducir un numero entre 1-31");
        //Aqui usas el codigo que tengas para obtener es numero de dia y lo almacenas en una variable numeroDia
        if(MIN_DIA<=numeroDia<=31{
            flagDia = true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("El numero introducido no es valido, debe estar comprendido entre 1-31");
        }
    }
}
```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo y seguro que mejores que la que te he propuesto.

Answer (score 0):

Tampoco termino de comprender tu pregunta, pero te dejo este ejemplo que creo que puede ayudarte.

```
package fechas;

import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PedirDiaMes {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Variables */
        int var = 0;
        Month month;
        boolean condition = false;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        /* Pedir mes y que sea correcto. */
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce un mes en valor numérico (1 - 12):");

            var = keyboard.nextInt();

            if( var > 12 || var < 1 ) {
                System.out.println("Valor erróneo. Vuelve a intentarlo");
            } else {
                condition = true;
            }

        } while (!condition);

        condition = false; // reseteo para reutilizar

        /*Pedir día del mes y que sea correcto*/
        month = Month.of(var);
        var = 0;

        do {
            System.out.printf("El mes introducido es %s. El cual tiene como máximo %d días.%n", month, month.maxLength());
            System.out.println("Introduce un día válido para este mes: ");

            var = keyboard.nextInt();

            if( var > month.maxLength() || var < 1 ) {
                System.out.println("Valor erróneo. Vuelve a intentarlo");
            } else {
                condition = true;
            }

        } while (!condition);

        System.out.printf("El mes introducido es %s. El día introducido es %d.", month, var);
    }
}
```